# Is this grammatically correct? If it's not then what's the correct way to say it?

Tags: grammar, grammaticality

Every supernatural thing that has happened to me came from the enemy.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to say the same--or nearly the same--thing. Your way of expressing your thought is perfectly grammatical.

You could play around with verb tenses by saying, for example,

> Every supernatural thing that has happened to me *has come* from the enemy.

Or you could change the wording slightly by saying

> Every supernatural thing that has happened to me can be traced to the enemy.

Or,

> Every supernatural thing that has happened to me originated with the enemy.

Or,

> The enemy has been the source of every supernatural thing that has happened to me.

Take your pick of any of the above sentences, if for some reason you are not satisfied with how your original sentence sounds.